# How to get a nested map value from web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, mapping

In contract:

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public spentLimit;
```

How to retrieve `spentLimit[a][b]` for given `a` and `b` from web3.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider adding the following function to your smart contract:

```
function getSpentLimit(address a, address b) public view returns (uint256) {
   return spentLimit[a][b];
}
```

then you can call this function in your smart contract using web3.js using a and b as parameters

Answer (score 3):

Your public state variable already creates a getter function. In ether.js, the spent limit would be accessible with yourContract.spentLimit(a,b), it must be similar with web3,js.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your solidity codes looks like this.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract aakash4dev {
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public spentLimit;

    function put_data(address a,address b,uint _limit) public {
        spentLimit[a][b]=_limit;
    }
    
    function get_data(address a,address b) public view returns(uint){
        return spentLimit[a][b];
    }
}
```

then Javascript (NodeJS) codes to put_data and get_data will be like this:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("<RPC Provider link>");
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("<Private key>");
const setting={
    from: "<Your wallet address>",
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(210000),
    maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('40', 'gwei')),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('40', 'gwei')),
}

ABI="{<ABI Code>}"
contractadddress="0x<Contract Address>"
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractadddress)

async function PutData(add1,add2,limit){
    let result=await contract.methods.put_data(add1,add2,limit).send(setting)
        .then((receipt)=>{ return receipt})
        .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
    return result
}

async function GetData(add1,add2){
    let result=await contract.methods.call(add1,add2)
    return result
}
```